# Translate html select into select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have difficult html select. How I can translate this html select into select_tag?

```
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-select">
                <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                <span class="btn-select-value">Select an Item</span>
                <span class='btn-select-arrow fa fa-chevron-down'></span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Option 1</li>
                    <li>Option 2</li>
                    <li>Option 3</li>
                    <li>Option 4</li>
                </ul>
            </a>
```